# Getting undefined data when i called a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a question that i've been trying to solve for hours.

My problem is that I'm getting the data faster than my services to load.

**gen-service**

```
function genEmpId() {
settingsService.getSettings().then(function (data) {
    var comId = data.data[0].companyId;
    console.log(comId);
    var test = comId + ' - ';
    return test;
});}
```

**controller**

```
function genId() {
   var data = genService.genEmpId();
   console.log(data); // getting the data too fast how to put a callback ?
}
```

So when my controller load its calling the service but im getting an undefined return value.

Comment: `genEmpId` isn't returning anything.

Comment: Just a minor thing, is your service included before your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, In your code you not returning anything and another thing is it's async call to you have to wait until it finishes.

```
// gen-service

function genEmpId() {
  return settingsService.getSettings().then(function (data) {
    var comId = data.data[0].companyId;
    console.log(comId);
    var test = comId + ' - ';
    return test;
  });
}

// controller

function genId() {
  var data = genService.genEmpId().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that it only works with an `$http` request

Comment: can  you add `settingsService.getSettings()` function also.

Comment: you see that `getEmpId` function is not a promise there. how can you wait for it to resolve ? @RahulSharma

Comment: @UsmanRana I'm returning another function promise from genEmpId function. so it'll wait until it resolves.

Comment: Thanks I don't know why it works ?? I've missed the first return on settings service sorry.

Comment: @Priz just check how promises work, that will help you a lot.